# SQL Average of total days in DATA per month

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a SQL question.
I am trying to find the average injection volume per month. Currently my code takes the sum of all days of injection, and divides them by the **TOTAL DAYS in the month**.

```
Sum(W1."INJECTION_VOLUME" /
EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(W1."INJECTION_DATE"))) AS "AVGINJ"
```

This is not what I wanted.
I need to take the `injection_volume` and divide by the total days in the **DATA** .

ie. right now the data only 8 days of `injection volume`, lets say it is 3000.

So right now the sql is 3000/31.

I need to have it be 3000/8 (the total days in the **data** for the current month.)

Also, this should only be for the current month. All other completed months should be divided by the total days in the month.

Comment: What platform? SQL Server? Oracle? Postgres? You haven't indicated which field would indicate the day but here's a start:`SUM(W1.INJECTION_VOLUME) / COUNT(DISTINCT MyDateField)`. Note this adds up the totals _first_ then divides them, which is usually the correct way to get this kind of figure

Comment: Actually this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. In future please remember, the SQL tag on it's own doesn't mean much - you should also post the platform

Comment: Will do. It is "FINDER" database, which is an Oracle Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT
SUM(W1.INJECTION_VOLUME) / COUNT(DISTINCT MyDateField)
FROM MyTable
WHERE X=Value
```

This gives you what you're after

```
SUM(W1.INJECTION_VOLUME) is the total volume for the dataset
```

Gives you the number of days, no matter how many records you have

```
COUNT(DISTINCT MyDateField)
```

So if you have 100 records but only 5 actual unique days in this time, this expression gives you 5

Note that this kind of calc is normally worked out with

```
SUM(A) / SUM(B)
```

not

```
SUM(A/B)
```

They give you completely different answers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the average of the data for the current month you will need to divide by the count in the month:

```
SUM(`W1`.`INJECTION_VOLUME` / COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `W1`.`INJECTION_DATE`)))
```

To get all other data as the full month you'll need to combine your code:

```
SUM(`W1`.`INJECTION_VOLUME` / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(`W1`.`INJECTION_DATE`)))
```

With an `IF`. So something like this:

```
SUM(
    IF(
        EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `W1`.`INJECTION_DATE`) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()), 
        `W1`.`INJECTION_VOLUME` / COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `W1`.`INJECTION_DATE`)), 
        `W1`.`INJECTION_VOLUME` / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(`W1`.`INJECTION_DATE`)
    )
)
```

Note: this is untested and I'm not sure about the RDBMS you are using so you may need to change the code slightly to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, This sounds like it should work. For some reason it says it is missing a parenthesis. I will mess around with it till it works. Thanks again

Comment: SUM(W1.INJECTION_VOLUME) / COUNT(DISTINCT MyDateField) this was the code I needed. Works perfectly for what I am trying to do.